# how to search based on multiple values from search option

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I'm trying to doing search option for multiple selection,
i want to retrieve the data from each selection from search option,
->if user choose one option than the search option will search according to the selection
->if user choose two options than the search option will search according to the selection and so on.

java code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
    PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();

    try {
        String status= request.getParameter("anystatus");
        String type= request.getParameter("alltype");
        String bedroom= request.getParameter("bedrooms");
        String bud= request.getParameter("budget");
        String loc= request.getParameter("location");

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/builders","root","root");
    String sql="select * from search where anystatus=?,all-type=?,bedrooms=?,budget=?,location=?";

    PreparedStatement pt= con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pt.setString(1, status);
    pt.setString(1, type);
    pt.setString(1, bedroom);
    pt.setString(1, bud);
    pt.setString(1, loc);
    ResultSet rs=pt.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()) {
```

jsp code:

```
            <div
            class="inline-search-area ml-auto mr-auto d-none d-xl-block d-lg-block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-6 search-col">
                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="anystatus"
                        onchange="purpose()" id="purpose">
                        <option value="rent">For Rent</option>
                        <option value="sale">For Sale</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-6 search-col">
                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="alltype"
                        onchange="propertytype()">
                        <option value="all">All Type</option>
                        <option value="apartment">Apartments</option>
                        <option value="independenthouse">Independent House</option>
                        <option value="villa">Villa</option>
                        <option value="commercialpurpose">Commercial Purpose</option>
                        <option value="openplots">Open Plots</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-6 search-col"
                    id="searchbedroom">
                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="bedrooms">
                        <option>Bedrooms</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-6 search-col"
                    id="searchsqft">
                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="sqft">
                        <option>Sqft</option>
                        <option>1K-2K sqfts</option>
                        <option>2K-4K sqfts</option>
                        <option>4K-6K sqfts</option>
                        <option>6K-10K sqfts</option>
                        <option>10K+ sqfts</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-6 search-col"
                    id="rentbudget">
                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="budget">
                        <option>Budget</option>
                        <option>2K-5K</option>
                        <option>6K-10K</option>
                        <option>10K-15K</option>
                        <option>15K+</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-6 search-col"
                    id="salebudget">
                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="budget">
                        <option>Budget</option>
                        <option>20L-30L</option>
                        <option>30L-50L</option>
                        <option>50L-1Cr</option>
                        <option>1Cr+</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-6 search-col">
                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="location">
                        <option>location</option>
                        <option>Hyderabad</option>
                        <option>Bangalore</option>
                        <option>Chennai</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-6 search-col">
                    <button class="btn button-theme btn-search btn-block" onclick="mySearch()">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i><strong>Search</strong>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm having doubt here `where anystatus=?,all-type=?,bedrooms=?,budget=?,location=?`, it needs to be either `and` or `or`

Answer (score 0):

You need to form your sql query depending on the number for search fields something on these lines
                String sql="select * from search where ";

```
            if (status != null || status != "")
                sql += " anystatus=? ";

            if (type != null || type != "")
                sql += " AND all-type=?"

            //and so on..
```

Then setting the values to the parameters also need to be done in a similar way

Also I see you are using the values to the first parameter only. You need to specify something like this

```
            pt.setString(1, status);
            pt.setString(2, type);
            pt.setString(3, bedroom);
            pt.setString(4, bud);
            pt.setString(5, loc);
```

Comment: can you please briefly explain how to set the values to the parameters

Comment: I have already shown in my answer how to set. You need to go through some tutorials..